# Using if Manipulation / method on button array

Tags: android

I am trying to create a TIC TAC TOE application in Android.

I have created a array of buttons

```
 public Button buttons[] = null;
```

In the `onCreate()` method I fetch the Buttons from the XML file.

```
    buttons[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
    buttons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    buttons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    buttons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    buttons[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    buttons[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    buttons[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    buttons[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    buttons[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
```

For each button, there is a different function. For example

```
    public void midBTMCLicked(View arg0) {

    if (Clicked == true) {
        buttons[7].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.x);
        Clicked = false;
    } else {
        buttons[7].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.o);
        Clicked = true;

    }
    buttons[7].setEnabled(false);
    Log.i("buttonCLicked","button middle at the lower line clicked,");
}
```

and now, after i  wrote the code of the Onclick , I'm trying to check for the winner

There is a problem inside my `if` statement.
I want to check if the background of the button changed.

```
public void CheckForWinner(View arg0)
{
    if ( buttons[0].setBackground()== buttons[1].setBackground()
        && buttons[1].setBackground()==buttons[2].setBackground())
     {}
}
```

The problem is that: `buttons[1].setBackground()...` gives me an Error.

Comment: setBackgroung used to set background to view for getting the background you have to use getBackground()

Comment: Can you give us the error ? I suppose it is either a NullPointerException or an ArrayOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, you cannot initialize an array like that

```
public Button buttons[] = null;
```

You should use the array contructor :

```
public Button buttons[] = new Button[9];
```

Secondly, you cannot compare the backgrounds like this.

Construct another array that save the state of the button like :

Integer[] buttonState = new Integer[9];

And then you can say that if the case is empty, `buttonState[i] = 0`, 1 for *X* and 2 for *O* . And in your `if` condition you compare the states like that :

```
public void CheckForWinner(View arg0)
    {
    if ( stateButtons[0] == stateButtons[1]
        && stateButtons[1] == stateButtons[2] )
     {
       // Do something
     }
}
```